# Strategies for mass insertion in MySQL

Tags: mysql, architecture, redis

My app would be consuming data from multiple API's . This data can either be a single event or a batch of events. The data I am dealing with is click streams, where my app would run a cron job every minute to fetch data with our partners using their API's and eventually save everything to MySQL for detailed analysis. I am looking for ways to buffer this data somewhere, and then batch insert it to MySQL.
For example, say I receive a batch of 1000 click events with one API call, what data structures can I use to buffer it in Redis, and then eventually have a worker process to consume this data and insert to MySQL.
One simple approach would be to just fetch the data and store it to MySQL just like that. But since I am dealing with ad tech, where the size and the velocity of the data is always subject to change, this hardly seems like an approach to start with.
Oh, and the app would be built on top of Spring Boot and Tomcat.

Any help/discussion would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. If you want/need to buffer your data, just buffer your data. You can do this in your app in e.g. an array/list/... (in memory), you can add a redis layer, or don't buffer at all. How can we tell you what data structure you have to use exactly without seeing any code/data/structure/model? Btw, MySQL can usually handle 1000 new rows per minute (and actually per second too). So maybe test the simple approach first. If you organize your code correctly, you should be able to transparently add a cache layer without much effort when it starts to get too slow.